# Entityqueue - Handler drop down is empty after installation

Tags: 7, entities

I have just installed the [Entityqueue module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) on my drupal 7x site. However, when I go to the `/admin/structure/entityqueue/add` page, the Handler dopwn down is empty and therefore the form will not validate so I cannot create a new list.

I've checked the `\modules\entityqueue\plugins\entityqueue\handler` folder and the simple handler is present along with it's class file.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the module but it was still appearing in the Modules list and I could not re-install it for this reason. However when I re-enabled it and saved, the Simple Handler appeared in the drop down. Good grief.